# run firefox in redhat enterprise server 6

Tags: linux, firefox

My box is redhat 64bit, i download  firefox-17.0.1.tar.bz2, and try to rpm and run it.
i stop at error like this,

```
"XPCOMGlueLoad error for file /opt/firefox/libxpcom.so:
libxul.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
Couldn't load XPCOM."
```

i look for solutions and learn  LD_DEBUG is a great tool, but i cannot deal with the result and hope someone could help me run firefox.

```
      [root@sun firefox]#LD_DEBUG=libs ./firefox
      5280:     find library=libpthread.so.0 [0]; searching
      5280:      search cache=/etc/ld.so.cache
      5280:       trying file=/lib/libpthread.so.0
      5280:
      5280:     find library=libdl.so.2 [0]; searching
      5280:      search cache=/etc/ld.so.cache
      5280:       trying file=/lib/libdl.so.2
      5280:
      5280:     find library=libstdc++.so.6 [0]; searching
      5280:      search cache=/etc/ld.so.cache
      5280:       trying file=/usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6
      5280:
      5280:     find library=libm.so.6 [0]; searching
      5280:      search cache=/etc/ld.so.cache
      5280:       trying file=/lib/libm.so.6
      5280:
      5280:     find library=libgcc_s.so.1 [0]; searching
      5280:      search cache=/etc/ld.so.cache
      5280:       trying file=/lib/libgcc_s.so.1
      5280:
      5280:     find library=libc.so.6 [0]; searching
      5280:      search cache=/etc/ld.so.cache
      5280:       trying file=/lib/libc.so.6
      5280:
      5280:
      5280:     calling init: /lib/libpthread.so.0
      5280:
      5280:
      5280:     calling init: /lib/libc.so.6
      5280:
      5280:
      5280:     calling init: /lib/libgcc_s.so.1
      5280:
      5280:
      5280:     calling init: /lib/libm.so.6
      5280:
      5280:
      5280:     calling init: /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6
      5280:
      5280:
      5280:     calling init: /lib/libdl.so.2
      5280:
      5280:
      5280:     initialize program: ./firefox
      5280:
      5280:
      5280:     transferring control: ./firefox
      5280:
      5280:
      5280:     calling init: /opt/firefox/libnspr4.so
      5280:
      5280:
      5280:     calling init: /opt/firefox/libplc4.so
      5280:
      5280:
      5280:     calling init: /opt/firefox/libplds4.so
      5280:
      5280:
      5280:     calling init: /opt/firefox/libnssutil3.so
      5280:
      5280:
      5280:     calling init: /opt/firefox/libnss3.so
      5280:
      5280:
      5280:     calling init: /opt/firefox/libsmime3.so
      5280:
      5280:
      5280:     calling init: /opt/firefox/libssl3.so
      5280:
      5280:
      5280:     calling init: /opt/firefox/libmozsqlite3.so
      5280:
      5280:
      5280:     calling init: /opt/firefox/libmozalloc.so
      5280:
      5280:     find library=libXrender.so.1 [0]; searching
      5280:      search cache=/etc/ld.so.cache
      5280:      search path=/lib/tls/i686/sse2:/lib/tls/i686:/lib/tls/sse2:/lib/tls:/lib/i686/sse2:/lib/i686:/lib/sse2:/lib:/usr/lib/tls/i686/sse2:/usr/lib/tls/i686:/usr/lib/tls/sse2:/usr/lib/tls:/usr/lib/i686/sse2:/usr/lib/i686:/usr/lib/sse2:/usr/lib                (system search path)
      5280:       trying file=/lib/tls/i686/sse2/libXrender.so.1
      5280:       trying file=/lib/tls/i686/libXrender.so.1
      5280:       trying file=/lib/tls/sse2/libXrender.so.1
      5280:       trying file=/lib/tls/libXrender.so.1
      5280:       trying file=/lib/i686/sse2/libXrender.so.1
      5280:       trying file=/lib/i686/libXrender.so.1
      5280:       trying file=/lib/sse2/libXrender.so.1
      5280:       trying file=/lib/libXrender.so.1
      5280:       trying file=/usr/lib/tls/i686/sse2/libXrender.so.1
      5280:       trying file=/usr/lib/tls/i686/libXrender.so.1
      5280:       trying file=/usr/lib/tls/sse2/libXrender.so.1
      5280:       trying file=/usr/lib/tls/libXrender.so.1
      5280:       trying file=/usr/lib/i686/sse2/libXrender.so.1
      5280:       trying file=/usr/lib/i686/libXrender.so.1
      5280:       trying file=/usr/lib/sse2/libXrender.so.1
      5280:       trying file=/usr/lib/libXrender.so.1
      5280:
      5280:     find library=libxul.so [0]; searching
      5280:      search cache=/etc/ld.so.cache
      5280:      search path=/lib/i686:/lib:/usr/lib            (system search path)
      5280:       trying file=/lib/i686/libxul.so
      5280:       trying file=/lib/libxul.so
      5280:       trying file=/usr/lib/libxul.so
      5280:
      5280:     find library=libxul.so [0]; searching
      5280:      search cache=/etc/ld.so.cache
      5280:      search path=/lib/i686:/lib:/usr/lib            (system search path)
      5280:       trying file=/lib/i686/libxul.so
      5280:       trying file=/lib/libxul.so
      5280:       trying file=/usr/lib/libxul.so
      5280:
XPCOMGlueLoad error for file /opt/firefox/libxpcom.so:
libxul.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
      5280:     ./firefox: error: symbol lookup error: undefined symbol: NS_GetFrozenFunctions (fatal)
      5280:
      5280:     calling fini: /opt/firefox/libmozalloc.so [0]
      5280:
      5280:
      5280:     calling fini: /opt/firefox/libmozsqlite3.so [0]
      5280:
      5280:
      5280:     calling fini: /opt/firefox/libssl3.so [0]
      5280:
      5280:
      5280:     calling fini: /opt/firefox/libsmime3.so [0]
      5280:
      5280:
      5280:     calling fini: /opt/firefox/libnss3.so [0]
      5280:
      5280:
      5280:     calling fini: /opt/firefox/libnssutil3.so [0]
      5280:
      5280:
      5280:     calling fini: /opt/firefox/libplds4.so [0]
      5280:
      5280:
      5280:     calling fini: /opt/firefox/libplc4.so [0]
      5280:
      5280:
      5280:     calling fini: /opt/firefox/libnspr4.so [0]
      5280:
Couldn't load XPCOM.
      5280:
      5280:     calling fini: ./firefox [0]
      5280:
      5280:
      5280:     calling fini: /lib/libpthread.so.0 [0]
      5280:
      5280:
      5280:     calling fini: /lib/libdl.so.2 [0]
      5280:
      5280:
      5280:     calling fini: /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6 [0]
      5280:
      5280:
      5280:     calling fini: /lib/libm.so.6 [0]
      5280:
      5280:
      5280:     calling fini: /lib/libgcc_s.so.1 [0]
      5280:
      5280:
      5280:     calling fini: /lib/libc.so.6 [0]
      5280:
```

so what's my problem and how to solve? Thanks.

Comment: Why don't you install Firefox through your package manager?

Comment: my package manager?you mean the rpm or something else? i have no idea, give me a hint.

Comment: RHEL comes with `yum`, a package manager. Try running `yum install firefox`.

Comment: Thanks for your remindering.my box is not registered with RHN.so i have to rpm it manually.

Comment: Thanks for your help.i erase redhat's yum and install centos.

Answer (score 0):

We need to install the *libdbus-glib-1-2* package.

`yum install libdbus-glib-1-2 -y`

Done. Once again, I try to relaunch the Mozilla Firefox